# MongoDB Shell Script on Replica Set

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to run a javascript file against a mongodb replica set but it fails on line 2 with the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: test
Tue Jan 21 09:00:01.702 JavaScript execution failed:
    ReferenceError: conn is not defined at /opt/mongo-scripts/views-by-date.js:L2
failed to load: /opt/mongo-scripts/views-by-date.js
```

This is the content of the script:

```
var conn = new Mongo();
var db = conn.getDB("main"); // line 2
var date = ISODate();
...
```

This is the command I'm running on the bash shell:

```
mongo /opt/mongo-scripts/views-by-date.js
```

I'm assuming, though may well be wrong, it has something to do with it being a replica set as the script works on my local non-replica set mongo instance.

Comment: What happens if you comment the first line, and second line is `var db = db.getSisterDB("main")`?

Comment: Thanks @orid that has done the trick. Wanna create the answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

- Remove first line
- Change second line to `var db = db.getSisterDB("main")`